# Combining two linearly independent collections

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space, and let $\left\{u_1, \dots, u_k\right\} \subset V$ and $\left\{v_1, \dots, v_l\right\} \subset V$ be two linearly independent collections such that $v_i \notin \mathrm{span} \left(u_1, \dots, u_k\right)$ for every $i=1, \dots, l$.
Does it follow that $$\left\{u_1, \dots, u_k\right\} \cup \left\{v_1, \dots, v_l\right\}$$
is a linearly independent collection, that is,
$$ \sum_{j=1}^k \xi_k u_k + \sum_{j=1}^l \xi_{k+j} v_k = 0 \Rightarrow \left(\xi_1{,}\ \xi_2{,}\ \dots{,}\ \xi_{k+l}\right)=\overline{0}. $$

What is the easiest way to see that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not true in general.

Take $V=\mathbb R^3$, $u_1=(1,1,0)$, $u_2=(0,1,0)$, $v_1=(0,0,1)$ and $v_2=(1,0,1)$. Clearly $\{u_1,u_2\}$ and $\{v_1,v_2\}$ are sets of lineraly independent vectors, and $v_i\notin \mathrm{span}(u_1,u_2)$, $i=1,2$.
But $\{u_1,u_2,v_1,v_2\}$ is not a set of linearly independent vectors.